# Reference backend.tf from separate folder

Tags: terraform

I have a directory structure like below where I have tf state files in s3 bucket

```
Main folder-> environment -> prod -> backend.tf
                          -> dev. -> backend.tf

Main folder -> *.tf files
```

I am curious to know if I can some how refrence dev/backend.tf while doing `terraform init` on Main folder.

if i try `terraform init -backend-config=./dev/backend.tf` it ignores the backend.tf details and creates local tfstate file

Comment: What output do you see?

Comment: What exactly is in the different backend.tf files?

Answer (score 1):

-backend-config is use to configure the state backend. Take a look at this: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/settings/backends/configuration. And, it can be anywhere in your computer.

Your ***terraform init*** can use -backend-config=./dev/backend.conf, where the content is just the variables that the state backend uses. For example, for aws, the file contents look like this:

```
encrypt = true 
bucket = "hella-buckets" 
dynamodb_table = "terraform-state-lock-dynamo" 
key = "terraform.tfstate" 
region = "us-east-1"
```

Comment: This was really helpful. I had to include quotes around my backend file path. Maybe this is because I am using PowerShell on Windows? This is what worked for me: `-backend-config="./env.dev.tfbackend"`